# how can get List of users in active directory using LINQ to LDAP?

Tags: c#, winforms, linq, active-directory

I want to access to ActiveDirectory using LINQ to LDAP and I want to Get List of All users in that
how can I do that?

Comment: I have included very useful link related to this subject on  my  post. plz check that.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can try something like below.

```
using ActiveDs;
using BdsSoft.DirectoryServices.Linq;
using System.Linq.Expressions;
using System.DirectoryServices;

[DirectorySchema( "user", typeof( IADsUser ) )]
class User
{
    public string Name { get; set; }

    public string sAMAccountName { get; set; }

    public string objectCategory { get; set; }

    public string mail { get; set; }

    public string Description { get; set; }

    [DirectoryAttribute( "PasswordLastChanged", DirectoryAttributeType.ActiveDs )]
    public DateTime PasswordLastSet { get; set; }

    [DirectoryAttribute("distinguishedName")]
    public string Dn { get; set; }

    [DirectoryAttribute("memberOf")]
    public string[] Groups { get; set; }

}
```

Use this code to access AD from a console app, placing your AD server in the below code:

```
static void Main( string[] args )
{

    IEnumerable<User> users = GetADUsers();

    Console.WriteLine( "Users: " + users.Count().ToString() );

}

static DirectoryEntry ROOT = new DirectoryEntry( "LDAP://MyADDomainLocation.com" );

private static IEnumerable<User> GetADUsers()
{
    IEnumerable<User> users;

    var usersDS = new DirectorySource<User>( ROOT, SearchScope.Subtree );

            users = from usr in usersDS
                    where usr.Name == "A*" // FIlter A then any character(s)
                    select usr;

     users = users.OrderBy( user => user.Name ).ToList(); // Sort them alphabetically by name.

    return users;
}
```

For more information check [**Get All Users using C# with Linq To Active Directory**](http://omegacoder.com/?p=236)

and [**LINQ to LDAP**](http://linqtoldap.codeplex.com/)

For **.NET Core or Standard**, please see [**Chris D's answer**](https://stackoverflow.com/a/53732624/2356600), below.

For get comprehensive knowledge about this subject check [**(Almost) Everything In Active Directory via C#**](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/18102/Howto-Almost-Everything-In-Active-Directory-via-C)

I hope this will help to you.

Comment: thanks a lot my friend,it's great,i have another question : your code runs on server with AD,i can run this app on another computer(a computer that joined to domain) what's the LDAP address in this case?

Comment: @SirwanAfifi Glad to hear that it helped.For your question you can refer this article http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/18102/Howto-Almost-Everything-In-Active-Directory-via-C

Comment: @Sampath Would you recommend using LINQ to LDAP?

Comment: @user2609980 Yes.If you can read this, you can realize that too.http://linqtoldap.codeplex.com/

Comment: @Sampath can you help me with my question [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21939802/using-linq-to-ldap-to-query-the-active-directory-how-to-define-directoryschema)? I do not understand nor can I find how to define the `DirectorySchema`.

Answer (score 0):

Sorry to reply to such an old question, but I felt it needed an updated answer. I wrote a .NET Standard library for this:

- Linq2Ldap.Core ([NuGet](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Linq2Ldap.Core/), [GitHub](https://github.com/cdibbs/linq2ldap.core)) The platform-independent core library that can translate from Expressions into LDAP filters, and parse them back out, again.

It has two wrapper libraries for Active Directory:

- Linq2Ldap.Protocols ([NuGet](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Linq2Ldap.Protocols/), [GitHub](https://github.com/cdibbs/linq2ldap)) - A thin wrapper around Linq2Ldap.Core + System.DirectoryServices.Protocols.
- Linq2Ldap ([NuGet](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Linq2Ldap/), [GitHub](https://github.com/cdibbs/linq2ldap)) - A thin wrapper for System.DirectoryServices.

The heart of it can transpile between `Expression<Func<T, bool>>`s and LDAP filters. The models (`T`) referenced by the Expressions must implement an interface, `IEntry`, that basically defines a fancy indexer class that you'd use like this: `m => m["cn"] == "someuser"`. You can also create special properties to alias your directory attributes, too. Please see the project wiki for more info.